# Should not the description for "convert to wiki" be changed?

Tags: support, community-wiki, moderator-tools

The description that I see for the moderator's "convert to wiki" action says:

> Community wiki questions don't accrue rep and have a lower full editing reputation threshold. **Questions should be manually converted to community wiki when they are marginal fits or 'list of X' questions that contain enough value to avoid deletion.** This affects the question and all answers.

Should not the sentence I highlighted be changed?
If I understand well, a question that is a marginal fit should be edited to make it a perfect fit, and list questions that contain enough value to avoid deletion should be locked for historical significance; in neither the cases a question should be made Community Wiki (except, maybe, in very exceptional cases).